# E/Volley: [217] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 415

Tags: java, android

This is My register request code when i am trying to register in our local server i got this error. "E/Volley: [217] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code".

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    public static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.0.2:6060/api/v1/mobileuser/savemobileUser";

    private HashMap<String,String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String email, String city, int phoneno, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name",name);
        params.put("email",email);
        params.put("city",city);
        params.put("phoneno",phoneno +"");
        params.put("password",password);
        System.out.println(params);
    }
    public HashMap<String, String> getParams(){
        return params;
    }
}
```

-------/*this is my register class*/----------

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText etName, etEmail, etMobile, etPassword, /*etRePassword*/ etCity;
    Button register;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        etMobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        etCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCity);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        //etRePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rePassword);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String name = etName.getText().toString();
        final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        final String city = etCity.getText().toString();
        final int phoneno = Integer.parseInt(etMobile.getText().toString());

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Registration failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create().show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
       RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name,email,city,phoneno,password,responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to trace `response` from `onResponse()` ,i think problem is on `jsonResponse.getBoolean("success")` line.

Comment: hi i am using springboot for backend.. can you check ithttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026726/this-is-my-controller-and-repository-that-is-develop-using-springboot